# Alignment between HTML and its text

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping HTML contents using BeautifulSoup and would like to keep a way to go back and forth between the actual HTML and its getText() attribute.

```
>>> html = "<p>Test</p>"
```

Feed it into BeautifulSoup

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Now I can easily get its text version, without html attributes :

```
>>> text = soup.get_text()
>>> print(text)
"Test"
```

Is there a way to have a mapping (alignment) between index locations of each character between `html` and the `text` ? I need to do processing on `text` but then modify the contents in `html`.

Here, it'd mean :

```
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10
< | p | > | T | e | s | t | < | / | p | >
```

&

```
0 | 1 | 2 | 3
T | e | s | t
```

So alignment would be `[(3,0), (4,1), (5,2), (6,3)]`.

Of course the example is straightforward but I'd need it for very complex and big HTML files. Does that ring a bell for someone ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify at least some context of why this is required.

The problem seems to be identifying the offset between actual html source code and the contained text (accounting for the source code character offset introduced by the tag before and after). I don't use this library myself but here goes.

The problem seems to be resolvable entirely with the Python `re` module. I am aware that [soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) has some hints about their own utilisation of `re` string searching but it's not very detailed, so I will discuss the python re library instead as it seems similar:

**this resolution assumes and hinges upon the premise that the contained text within a tag in source code is unique**

Programmatically create a regex like this: 
 `"<TAGNAME [\w ]*> (STRING CONTENTS)<TAGNAME/>"`. This regex utilises groups so that by using `match.group(0).start()` you can get the start position of the whole tag in source code, and using `match.group(1).start()` you will get the position of the `STRING CONTENTS`. By finding the difference between these two positions you will be able to generate a storable offset integer which you can just employ instead of creating a dictionary mapping (the offset could be used to generate the dictionary nonetheless).

N.B: By bearing reference to [this answer](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) I learned that soup `(the output of beautifulsoup(html, 'html.parser'))`changes the structure of the input string, thus would not be reliable to use versus the untouched string literal source code